# I tried using makemigrations to connect the website to the server but got the "password authentication failed for user 'postgres'"error message

Tags: django, postgresql

I think the problem might be where I saved my local_settings.py but not too sure about that. Does anyone have any idea on what I could do here?

[Picture of Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8X3fj.png)

Answer (score 0):

It may help you.

You need to edit the `pg_hba.conf` file, in my case I use Ubuntu and the file is on the path below. 12 is the `postgres` version.

This example uses Vim but you can use any editor.

```
$ sudo vim /etc/postgresql/12/main/pg_hba.conf
```

Then change this line from:

```
local   all             postgres                                md5
```

To:

```
local   all             postgres                                trust
```

Save, close the file and finally run

```
$ sudo service postgresql restart
```

Now the application might to be able to access `postgresql` using `postgres` user without password.